# Finding border of rotated image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've got a rotated image like this: [image]

What I would like to do is find the edges of the image. That is I would like to find the red edges as seen in this image:
[image]

I've tried to find the first and last non-zero elements and then use those as the coordinates of the edge. This is fine (if I could actually get it to work) but it is not extensible in that the red border may need to be extended to get a 'thicker' border. Essentially I'm trying to find the border because I need to move effects that occur at the edge of the rotated image that I need to get rid of. If someone could point me in the direction of a suitable answer (something along the lines of a bounding box or similar) I would much appreciate it!

**EDIT**
Moved my edit to an answer as per [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232610/jonas)'s suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by thicker border? Anyway, you may convert this image into binary image with 0 as threshold and then use the minimum bounding rectangle found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects). But converting into binary is not a robust approach I must say.

Comment: @Parag Sorry what I mean is that if there is a 1 pixel thick and I use it to remove the border, I may want to extend the removal further into the image (2 pixels in, 3, etc..). Also I've just used a(a>0) = 255; to create a binary image and it *seems* to work. Thanks for the suggestion and I'll try it out.

Comment: @user901898: If you found a useful answer by yourself, add it as an actual answer below, rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a somewhat suitable answer. From user [Parag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586200/parag)'s advice I binary thresholded the image (anything greater than 0). I then applied a Sobel edge detection. This creates a binary image with the image edges and then I use morphological dilation to 'expand' the border as necessary.

The code I used:

```
I = imread('outputTest.jpg');
B = I;
B(B > 0) = 255;
BW = edge(B,'sobel');
SE = strel('rectangle', [5 5]);
BW = imdilate(BW,SE);
I2 = I;
I2(BW > 0) = 0;
```

As [Parag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586200/parag) mentions binarising the image isn't the most robust way of solving this but due to the way my images are formed before I see them, I'm certain this will be sufficient for my case at least.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to calculate the corners of rotated image by using the rotation angle.